# Double fixed header and footer - preferably dynamic

Tags: css, flexbox, tablelayout

I am not sure if what I need can even be done, but I'd like a flex (or CSS including table layout if that will work) solution to provide double fixed (fixed - not sticky) headers and footers as follows:

```
***header one - fixed - dynamic height***
***header two - fixed - dynamic height***
***content - scrolls as needed***
***fixed one - fixed - dynamic height***
***footer two - fixed - dynamic height***
```

I've spent days searching and trying things and have probably come closest with [this js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trfabpLm/2) which works overall except that the header and footer content do not wrap if they exceed the page width. I can consider fixed heights if needed, but would prefer dynamic. Also if it matters, sometimes header two and footer one will not be on the page.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I think this works.

You have to have max-height in there otherwise the column will expand, I chose 100vh.

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JXByVg)

I'm assuming you didn't mean that the headers/footers were `position:fixed` as they would then be out of the document flow and could not affect the height of the non-positioned elements.

Instead, I assume you mean that the main content must fit between them regardless of their size and overflow as required.

I've added an 'expanding' hover to the content section so you can see the overflow take effect.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
div {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.one {
  background: lightblue;
}
.two {
  background: lightgreen;
}
main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-Y: auto;
  background: pink;
}
main:hover .expander {
  height: 1000px;
}
p {
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0;
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header one">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, alias mollitia. Laborum et cupiditate</p>
  </div>
  <div class="header two">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex excepturi molestiae voluptates nesciunt, recusandae error,</p>
  </div>
  <main>
    <div class="expander"></div>
  </main>
  <div class="footer one">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur incidunt, esse quaerat illum ipsa. Reiciendis corrupti aliquid placeat</div>
  <div class="footer two">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum rerum tempore dolor tenetur expedita eligendi nemo numquam veniam laboriosam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```